# Operation in Background on Android

Tags: android, service, coroutine

I'm Developing an app communicate with device in bluetooth

I want my app keep operation like parsing data from device and save in db even when the app is on background ( I mean the activity is not visible )

But when my app goes background, after a few minute, the operation stopped even if the operation is not on main thread.

So I used a Service to keep operating on background, and I can achieve my goal.
But there are some questions.

I used a foreground service to make my app operating in background. But after I start a service, the whole operation including coroutines on viewmodelscope works even in background!!
Also even my service doing nothing but just started, however, the whole coroutines launched by activity keep working in background!! So I was going to move my code communicating with device on my service but didn't do it.
Why is this happening??

If I use boundService instead of foreground service, neither the service code and activity code works. Then I'm confusing why 'boundService' exist...

Can anyone help me to understand the Service component?? Is it normal case of using service??

and I started foreground service with notification, but I could not see the notification in status bar.
The [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#user-dismiss-notification) said foreground service must show notification..

Here is my service code

```
class BleService : Service() {
    companion object {
        const val CHANNEL_ID = "TEST"
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 1
    }
    private val binder = LocalBinder()
    private val job = SupervisorJob()
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        val pendingIntent = Intent(this, BleService::class.java).let { notificationIntent ->
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        }

        createNotificationChannel()

        val notification: Notification = Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Test")
            .setContentText("Test is running")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)

        scope.launch { test() }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        val nm = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        nm.createNotificationChannel(
            NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Test",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return binder
    }

    suspend fun test() {
        while (true) {
            delay(1000)
            println("test")
        }
    }

    inner class LocalBinder : Binder() {
        fun getService(): BleService {
            return this@BleService
        }
    }
}
```

Ny activity start service in  'onCreate' and stop it in 'onDestroy' by  `startForegroundService()` and `stopService()`

I tried to use `bindService()`, but in this case app didn't work on background. Even code in service either.
Should I move my device communicating code which use ble on my service??

Comment: Having a Foreground Service running keeps the whole app process alive. So any code running in the process, initiated by any class, will keep on running and will not be suspended.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation looks fine

Don't call stop service. If your activity stopped service will also got stopped. remove that code and it will work fine.